# Locking Quiz - Preventing opening another window during quiz

Tags: google-forms, lockscreen

Is it possible to get an app script code to stop users from opening another window/ tab while filing up a form/quiz? What are the other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible via Apps Script code. However, there are different ways you can achieve this depending on devices users log in to. For instance, there is this option [Use locked mode for quizzes](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7634943) for ChromeOS devices. Furthermore, if you have Google Workspace users, you can block by URLs using a  [Local policy](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532419?hl=en#zippy=%2Clinux%2Cmac%2Cwindows) or remotely from the [Admin console](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?#url_blocklist). These last 2 options, block users from navigating to other web URLs by using the wildcard "*" except the URLs you specify in the "Exceptions".

If you have other browsers installed in users'devices, then you can create a temporal Context-Aware access rule as specified in [these steps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9275380). With these rule and the correct Google Workspace edition, you can block access from any other browser except Chrome.